# AttributeError : 'list' object has no attribute 'to_sql'

Tags: python, mysql

Im trying to write a python script to take yahoo_finance data and place it in a mysql database. I can do it via a long winded way but Ive now discovered pandas and dataframe.to.sql.

I can't though get it to work- I keep getting the AttributeError. What am I doing wrong?

```
import yahoo_finance
from yahoo_finance import Share
import pandas as pd
import mysql.connector
from sqlalchemy import create_engine


engine = create_engine('mysql://user:pass@localhost')
data = Share('YHOO')
df= data.get_historical ('2016-03-24', '2017-03-24')
df.to_sql(name = daily_price, con = engine, if_exists = 'append', flavor = 'mysql')
```

Many thanks!

Comment: `df` is not a dataframe. Importing `pandas` won't suddenly make non-Pandas objects support Pandas methods.

Comment: I'm assuming `.get_historical()` just returns a `list`... not a `pandas.DataFrame`.

Comment: Brilliant- thanks for this- Once I got that I used df=pd.DataFrame(data) and it works- thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`pandas_datareader`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pandas-datareader) to get Yahoo data (this used to be `pandas.io`):

```
>>> import pandas_datareader.data as web
>>> data = web.get_data_yahoo('YHOO', '2016-03-24', '2017-03-24')
>>> # Or: web.DataReader('YHOO', 'yahoo', '2016-03-24', '2017-03-24')
>>> data
                 Open       High        Low      Close    Volume  Adj Close
Date                                                                       
2016-03-24  34.450001  34.869999  33.930000  34.860001  14118600  34.860001
2016-03-28  35.389999  35.450001  34.619999  35.230000  12981000  35.230000
2016-03-29  35.049999  36.430000  35.009998  36.320000  23603400  36.320000
2016-03-30  36.610001  37.279999  36.439999  36.560001  19849800  36.560001
...
>>> type(data)
pandas.core.frame.DataFrame
```

Now you can call `data.to_sql(...)`.